# How to reset input type range to 0 on volume slider when clicking on the mute button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have this volume slider:

```
 <input id="volume-slider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"></input>

      $("#volume-slider").on("change", function() {
        audio.volume = this.value;
        if (audio.volume === 0) {
          [... change class to make mute volume icon appear ...]
        } else {
          [... change class to make mute volume icon disappear ...]
        }
      });
```

This code is working fine. When the slider goes to 0, the mute speaker icon appears.

However, I want also the opposite.

I can make something like:

```
$("#speaker-button").on("click", function() {
audio.volume > 0 ? audio.volume = 0 : audio.volume = 0.5;
}
```

which works fine. However when I mute the volume setting `audio.volume` to `0` it does not move the input range slider. If I mute the volume using the mute button, I want the range slider to go to 0.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So set the slider value to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the slider value and trigger the change method.

Basic idea below and I added code that will unmute to the last known value instead of resetting it to 0.5.

```js
const audio = { volume : 0 }
let lastVolume
const slider = $("#volume-slider").on("change", function() {
  var val = +this.value;
  audio.volume = val
  if (val) lastVolume = val
  console.log(audio.volume)
}).change();

$("#mute").on("click", function () {
  var val = audio.volume === 0 ? (lastVolume || 0.5) : 0
  slider.val(val).change()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="volume-slider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"></input>

<button id="mute" type="button">Mute</button>
```